# BS4 close accordion when clicking outside card-body

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

I would like to collapse/close an accordion when clicking outside the card-body in Bootstrap 4. In Bootstrap 3 it was easy and worked [like this](https://codepen.io/yanny-dragnev/pen/oLyadQ). When clicking inside the card-body, the accordion shouldn't close.

```
if (!$(e.target).is('.panel-body')) {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');        
}
```

I need it to work with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery will collapse the accordion on outside body click.

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".panel-body" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$( ".panel-body" ).is(e.target) && !$( ".panel-body" ).has(e.target).length) {
        $('.panel-body').accordion('activate', -1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3><a href="#">Collapsible Area</a></h3>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
    Outside of Accordion
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. The accordion works fine, but when I click outside an open accordion (outside being away from card-body) I want it to close.

Comment: Oh I see. Apologies, I'll be back.

Comment: I can't get your example to work. The BS4 accordion doesn't have any "panel-body" class, but a card-body. When I replace this it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

**In bootstrap 4 `.panel-body` was replaced to `.card-body`**

**see JSFiddle:**https://jsfiddle.net/xdfLh6zp/ 
Here is work one:
I take example from here:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_collapse.asp

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
 if (!$(e.target).is('.card-body')) {
     $('.collapse').collapse('hide');     
    }
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div id="accordion">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
    Collapsible Group Item #2
  </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
      Collapsible Group Item #3
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is for Bootstrap 3 like in the working example. I need it to work for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: It semi works. When you click on the content inside the card-body, it also closes. It shouldn't do that

Comment: In bootstrap 4 `.panel-body` was replaced to `.card-body`